# Apache2: mod_rewrite with circular rewriting

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, alias

I want to load a `private` site for an specific subdomain without creating a new virtual host (for not creating and repeating the virtual host configuration), in the following way:

- The user writes priv.mydomain.com
- The `mod_rewrite` appends /priv to the URL without redirection.
- An `Alias` directive gets /priv and loads /other_system_path/private
- The `private` page is loaded but the user sees no changes in the URL.

My current config is as follows (inside the proper virtual host):

```
Alias /priv /other_system_path/private

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^priv\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) /priv [PT]
```

The `PT` flag is, if I'm not wrong, for repeating the process of URL mapping, which turns into being got for the `RewriteRule` again, since `priv.` remains in the URL.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try to add `RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false`

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm. Write it as an answer to accept it, if you know. Some explanation would be welcome. Anyway, I'm seing "/priv" in the browser.

Comment: `Anyway, I'm seing "/priv" in the browser` But you do not want to see it?

Comment: No, I prefer not to see it, for being even more transparent.

Comment: Do you want to say that `[PT]` makes a visual redirection? And I suggest to have `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /priv/$1 [PT]`

Comment: Finally, I've create a new virtual host for the proper subdomain, because my virtual host was inside a TLS connection, and rewrittings for each petition was causing me troubles (blank forms, javascript problems and so on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The PT flag is, if I'm not wrong, for repeating the process of URL
>   mapping, which turns into being got for the RewriteRule again, since
>   priv. remains in the URL

You can skip the rule for the subrequests by adding the following condition

```
RewriteCond %{IS_SUBREQ} false
```

According to manual

> IS_SUBREQ
>
> Will contain the text "true" if the request currently being
>   processed is a sub-request, "false" otherwise. Sub-requests may be
>   generated by modules that need to resolve additional files or URIs in
>   order to complete their tasks.

ps: and you need, as I think, `RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /priv/$1 [PT]`, so that any request will be transformed to the correct one, not just to the 'root' of the alias.